# JQuery - Replace DIV's content with Image

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV called MainDiv. I like to replace the content of the DIV with an image on click of a button. I tried 
in order to replace it within the click even in Jquery but something happened.

```
    $('#MainDiv').attr('src', 'images/Img1.jpg ');
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: A `div` doesn't have a `src` attribute like the `img` tag does.  You should try something like `$('#MainDiv').html('<img src="img.jpg">');` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#MainDiv").html( "<img src='images/Img1.jpg'>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('#MainDiv').replaceWith("<img id='MainDiv' src='images/Img1.jpg'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> <img src="" id="img"/> </div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">


$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#btn" ).click(function() {
        $("#img").attr("src", src);
   });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fbkft20e/)**